# Table view doesn't respond to touches when scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've never run into this and can't seem to find anyone else talking about this. I have a simple tableview in a view controller. For some reason, the tableview doesn't allow any touches when it is moving. User can't select a cell or stop the motion of the scroll when it's scrolling. Anyone ever encountered this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing something in a delegate method for UIScrollViewDelegate that is messing with the touch handling. Make sure you aren't blocking or doing anything otherwise weird in those methods.